# Another "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility

I´m getting cannot find symbol error in my code (symbol: method `setAr(boolean)`).

Here is my `Main.java` file:

```
class Vehicle {
    protected int marchs;
    protected int rode;
    public void xydar(int km) { System.out.print("\nxydei "+ km +" km!"); }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car() { this.rode = 4; }
    public void xydar(int km) {
    super.xydar(km);
    System.out.println(" Estou de car!");
    }
}
class CarLux extends Car {
    private boolean ar;
    public CarLux() { this.ar = true; }
    public void setAr(boolean newAr) { this.ar = newAr; }
    public void xydar(int km) {
        super.xydar(km);
        if (this.ar)
        System.out.println(" ON!");
        else System.out.println(" OFF!");
    }
}
public class Main {
public static void main(String []args) {
    Vehicle moto = new Vehicle();
    moto.xydar(90);
    Vehicle car1 = new Car();
    car1.xydar(100);
    Vehicle car2 = new CarLux();
    car2.xydar(400);
    car2.setAr(false);
    car2.xydar(400);
    }
}
```

How can I call `setAr()` method correctly? Can anyone help me? I´m new to Java.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `car2` as a `CarLux`, not a `Vehicle`.

```
CarLux car2 = new CarLux();
```

That's because your `setAr()` method is defined on `CarLux`.  `car2` is currently held in a variable of type `Vehicle`, so when you call a method of `car2` only the methods declared by `Vehicle` will be available.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, he does. Edit: derpy derpy derpy, types are your friend

Comment: @Timr:  He's *instantiating* a `CarLux`, but the object isn't a concrete instance of a `CarLux`.

Comment: I understand car2 is a CarLux, but why this code works to xydar method and calls the xydar from the correct subclass? Just because are the xydar method on Vehicle class? And a CarLux is a Vehicle, right? That's my headache.

Comment: @eightShirt: Correct.  `xydar` is *declared* in `Vehicle`.  Subclasses may override the *implementation*, which `CarLux` has done.  The [Java Tutorial for Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) will help you explore this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can call setAr method only through an object of type CarLux because this is method of CarLux not Vehicle so you have to cast car2 as CarLux then call method like this -

```
((CarLux)car2).setAr(false);
```